# how to manually add values to ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to manually add values to barplot for which the code you can see below.

eg. For banana

```
Stress = 10
Normal = 80
Nitrogen = 10
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Small multiple
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
    ggtitle("Studying 4 species..") +
    theme_ipsum() +
    xlab("")
```

Comment: What do you mean? Where/how do you want to manually add values to this plot?

Comment: Please include the packages you are using

Comment: I have added the packages. On the y axis I would like to have a scale in %.

Comment: For the banana. Stress and nitrogen should be only 10% whereas Normal should be 80%

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

`viridis` is not compatible with my version of R so I'm not really sure how that will look. I've commented out the relevant lines of code so the example is reproducible.

Applied `set.seed()` to the data to make it reproducible.

`geom_col()` option involves less typing than `geom_bar()`

`geom_text()` for automated labelling related to the values; Not clear if the reference in the question for labels to banana means labels only for banana or for all species. Have shown how to filter to apply labels to banana only, simply remove the filter if you need labels for all species. If you really want manual labels then creating a helper data frame is one way to go.

Not entirely clear what you mean by wanting a scale in %: have edited the axis title to include unit of measure as %. And modified y axis with `scale_y_continuous()` although have noticed that `hrbrthemes::scale_x_percent()` exists so you could explore how to use this function. Take your pick...

```r
library(ggplot2)
#library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data, aes(x = specie, y = value, fill = condition)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data = filter(data, specie == "banana"),
            aes(x = specie,
                y = value,
                label = paste(round(value, 0), "%")),
            position = "stack")+
  # scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1))+
  theme_ipsum() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Value [%]",
       title = "Studying 4 species..")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
```